# Showing message in fancybox after button set location in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox

Currently modifying a Magento add to cart functionality...

What we're attempting to achieve here is:-

From the category listing:-

## Scenario 1

When add to cart button is clicked, if product has options, show options in fancybox before the option to proceed to checkout is given.

Screenshot:

[image: Showing product with options in fancybox so can't be added to cart without selecting a required option.]

Live example: Pretty much any product on [this page](http://www.showermania.co.uk/showering/shower-trays/quadrant-shower-trays?manufacturer=51).

This is working as expected.

## Scenario 2

When add to cart button is clicked, if product has no options, show a 'product has been added to cart successfully' message with an option to 'checkout' or 'continue shopping' in fancybox.

Issue: Unable to achieve the desired on this one. What we do currently have is a popup notification that almost does the job which can be seen at [this page](http://www.showermania.co.uk/showering/showers/mixer-showers) (just select any product near the top to see in action).

This doesn't use fancybox however, it is a custom implementation that uses the following markup:-

```
<div id="fancybox<?php echo $_product->getId()?>" class="fancybox fancy-popupbox" style="position:absolute; display:none;">
<div class="popup-text"></div>
<div class="popup-buttons">
    <div style="float:left">
        <button onclick="setLocation('')" class="button btn-shop" title="Continue Shopping" type="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right">
        <button onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl();?>checkout/onepage')" class="button btn-checkout" title="Proceed to Checkout" type="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Proceed to Checkout') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Which is then called with:-

```
jQuery('.popup-text').html(data.message);
jQuery('.fancy-popupbox').show();
```

From within the success function in setLocationAjax function:-

```
function setLocationAjax(url,id){
    url += 'isAjax/1';
    url = url.replace("checkout/cart","ajax/index");
    jQuery('#ajax_loader'+id).show();
    try {
        jQuery.ajax( {
            url : url,
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data) {
                jQuery('#ajax_loader'+id).hide();
                jQuery('.popup-text').html(data.message);
                jQuery('.fancy-popupbox').show();
                setAjaxData(data,false);           
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
    }
}
```

Where this function is called from a modification to the add to cart button:-

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocationAjax('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>','<?php echo $_product->getId()?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

You can see the complete markup at the pages linked to above or you can take a look at the complete list.phtml file in use at [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/sjvcTBva) (includes full script also).

So, to summarise, we essentially want to modify scenario 2 so that it operates like scenario 1.

## Edit 1 from @JFK's Answer

It didn't seem to like your suggestion.

When I implemented...

```
jQuery.fancybox.open('.fancy-popupbox');
```

Console returned...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (obj){var opts;if(busy){return;}
busy=true;opts=typeof arguments[1]!=='undefined'?arguments[1]:{};selectedArray=[];selectedIndex=parseInt(opts.index,10)||0;if($.isArray(obj)){for(var i=0,j=obj.length;i<j;i++){if(typeof obj[i]=='object'){$(obj[i]).data('fancybox',$.extend({},opts,obj[i]));}else{obj[i]=$({}).data('fancybox',$.extend({content:obj[i]},opts));}}
selectedArray=jQuery.merge(selectedArray,obj);}else{if(typeof obj=='object'){$(obj).data('fancybox',$.extend({},opts,obj));}else{obj=$({}).data('fancybox',$.extend({content:obj},opts));}
selectedArray.push(obj);}
if(selectedIndex>selectedArray.length||selectedIndex<0){selectedIndex=0;}
_start();} has no method 'open'
```

So the complete script looked like this after implementation...

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.fancybox').fancybox(
        {
           hideOnContentClick : true,
           width: 382,
           autoDimensions: true,
           type : 'iframe',
           showTitle: false,
           scrolling: 'no',
           onComplete: function(){
            jQuery('#fancybox-frame').load(function() { // wait for frame to load and then gets it's height
                jQuery('#fancybox-content').height(jQuery(this).contents().find('body').height()+30);
                jQuery.fancybox.resize();
             });

           }
        }
    );
});
function showOptions(id){
    jQuery('#fancybox'+id).trigger('click');
}
function setAjaxData(data,iframe){
    if(data.status == 'ERROR'){
        alert(data.message);
    }else{
        if(jQuery('.block-cart')){
            jQuery('.block-cart').replaceWith(data.sidebar);
        }
        if(jQuery('.header .links')){
            jQuery('.header .links').replaceWith(data.toplink);
        }
        jQuery.fancybox.close();
    }
}
function setLocationAjax(url,id){
    url += 'isAjax/1';
    url = url.replace("checkout/cart","ajax/index");
    jQuery('#ajax_loader'+id).show();
    try {
        jQuery.ajax( {
            url : url,
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data) {
                jQuery('#ajax_loader'+id).hide();
                jQuery('.popup-text').html(data.message);
                //jQuery('.fancy-popupbox').show();
                jQuery.fancybox.open('.fancy-popupbox');
                setAjaxData(data,false);           
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
    }
}
```

Please point out if a further tweak would have been necessary. Thanks.

## Edit 2 Updated Fancybox

I've updated Fancybox from 1.3.4 to 2.1.4 (but this isn't on the live site linked to - it's updated on a dev version). So what we have needs rewriting to work with Fancybox 2 then it seems now.

## Edit3 Progress Update

I feel I'm almost there, I just need help on converting the below to the correct syntax (I think). If anyone could assist with this, that would be fab.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    $('.fancybox').fancybox(
        {
           hideOnContentClick : true,
           width: 382,
           autoDimensions: true,
           type : 'iframe',
           showTitle: false,
           scrolling: 'no',
           onComplete: function(){
            $('#fancybox-frame').load(function() { // wait for frame to load and then gets it's height
                $('#fancybox-content').height(jQuery(this).contents().find('body').height()+30);
                $.fancybox.resize();
             });

           }
        }
    );
}); 

function showOptions(id){
    $('#fancybox'+id).trigger('click');
}
function setAjaxData(data,iframe){
    if(data.status == 'ERROR'){
        alert(data.message);
    }else{
        if(jQuery('.block-cart')){
            jQuery('.block-cart').replaceWith(data.sidebar);
        }
        if(jQuery('.header .links')){
            jQuery('.header .links').replaceWith(data.toplink);
        }
        jQuery.fancybox.close();
    }
}
function setLocationAjax(url,id){
    url += 'isAjax/1';
    url = url.replace("checkout/cart","ajax/index");
    $('#ajax_loader'+id).show();
    try {
        jQuery.ajax( {
            url : url,
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data) {
                //jQuery('#ajax_loader'+id).hide();
                //jQuery('.popup-text').html(data.message);
                //jQuery('.fancy-popupbox').show();
                //jQuery.fancybox.open('.fancy-popupbox');
                jQuery.fancybox.open('.fancy-popupbox',{
                    // API options here
                });
                setAjaxData(data,false);           
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to display in fancybox is the contents of

```
<div id="fancybox<?php echo $_product->getId()?>" class="fancybox fancy-popupbox" style="position:absolute; display:none;">
...
</div>
```

then, instead of this line in your ajax `success` callback

```
jQuery('.fancy-popupbox').show();
```

try this

```
jQuery.fancybox.open('.fancy-popupbox');
```

assuming that you have properly loaded fancybox js/css files

If you want to add API options to fancybox, try this

```
jQuery.fancybox.open('.fancy-popupbox',{
    // API options here
});
```

Comment: Thanks @JFK. Please see my edit in the question to see results of your suggestion. This didn't seem to work but may be an error on my part.

Comment: @GeoffJackson are you sure you are using fancybox 2?? otherwise try `jQuery.fancybox('.fancy-popupbox');` because the `$.fancybox.open()` method only exist in v2.x. I notice in your edit your API options are for v1.3.4

Comment: Yes, sorry - I'm currently using version 1.3.4. Easier to modify your suggestion to suit this version or for me to upgrade the version of Fancybox in use? Thanks.