# Debugging 404 error page loading in Fancybox from script

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I'm not sure how to debug this particular issue at present.

If you view this [category page](http://www.showermania.co.uk/showering) for example and hit the 'Buy' button on the top product, a popup will appear, hit the 'Proceed to Checkout' button and a Fancybox modal appears briefly displaying a 404 error - would someone kindly use their browser dev tools and point out why it is loading the 404 error page within the Fancybox modal please?

The script that is controlling this has become a bit of a mess but I have provided it below for reference...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.fancybox').fancybox(
            {
               hideOnContentClick : true,
               width: 382,
               autoDimensions: true,
               type : 'iframe',
               showTitle: false,
               scrolling: 'no',
               onComplete: function(){
                jQuery('#fancybox-frame').load(function() { // wait for frame to load and then gets it's height
                    jQuery('.fancybox').height(jQuery(this).contents().find('body').height()+30);
                    jQuery.fancybox.resize();
                 });

               }
            }
        );
    });
    function showOptions(id){
        jQuery('#fancybox'+id).trigger('click'); //show the custom options on click if they exist
    }
    function setAjaxData(data,iframe){
        if(data.status == 'ERROR'){
            alert(data.message); //show error message if nothing to update
        }else{
            if(jQuery('.block-cart')){
                jQuery('.block-cart').replaceWith(data.sidebar); //otherwise update the cart in the sidebar block
            }
            if(jQuery('.header .links')){
                jQuery('.header .links').replaceWith(data.toplink); //otherwise update the cart in the header block
            }
            jQuery.fancybox.close();
        }
    }
    function setLocationAjax(url,id){
        url += 'isAjax/1';
        url = url.replace("checkout/cart","ajax/index");
        jQuery('#ajax_loader'+id).show();
        try {
            jQuery.ajax( {
                url : url,
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(data) {
                    jQuery('#ajax_loader'+id).hide(); //if success, hide #ajax_loader
                    jQuery('.popup-text').html(data.message); //if success, show .popup-text that says product is added to cart
                    jQuery('.fancy-popupbox').show(); //if success, show .fancy-popupbox content
                    //jQuery.fancybox.open('.fancy-popupbox');
                    setAjaxData(data,false);
                }
            });
        } catch (e) {
        }
    }
</script>
```

Please let me know if I can supply some further information on this.

Comment: Can't you use dev tools?

Comment: Not to debug javascript / jquery no :(

Comment: Well, I did it for you. See my answer! :)

Comment: Did I complete this for you? Let me know if there is anything else I can do...

Comment: Erm... no. You just copied what appeared in your Chrome console - this wasn't what I was asking for at all.

Comment: My apologies. I guess I misunderstood you.

Comment: You are still dragging issues from your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/q/18380380/1055987 you actually have two version of fancybox installed and mixing different API options. Also, inside your `onComplete` callback you are trying to set the `height` to the same selector (`.fancybox`) that fired fancybox, which I don't think you meant that. I guess your site needs more debugging that the simple 404.

Comment: Hi @JFK. Yes, you're right, I've struggled getting this one sorted and wondered if perhaps I'm including too much of one issue in the previous SO questions. Thanks for your input - I'm going to completely revert this element of the add to cart process and start afresh with one Fancybox version and setup and then come back to SO. (Where I've attempted so many others suggestions it's ended up a bit all over the place).

Answer (score -1):

The are the errors that the Chrome Tools detected:

``` Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"    from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.showermania.co.uk". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.``
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://static.ak.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.showermania.co.uk". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.``
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://s-static.ak.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.showermania.co.uk".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.``
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://static.ak.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.showermania.co.uk". Protocols, domains, and ports must match. chrome-extension://geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc/controllers/frame.js:1
Failed to load resource ```

Basically, your ports are incorrectly configured. As it said, "Protocols, domains, and ports must match."

Comment: I know how to view the console, I need help with actually debugging the jquery. Those errors aren't even related to the question (they are chrome extension / facebook script related).